# In function of the role of the user logged in an Angular application, the columns of the table must differ

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular table

```
<diV class="w-100">
   <app-table *ngIf="dataSource"
         ...
         ...
         [columns]="columns"
         [dataSource]="dataSource"
         [filtre]="filtre">
   </app-table>
</diV>
```

The .ts is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-liste-emetteur',
  templateUrl: './liste-emetteur.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./liste-emetteur.component.scss']
})

export class ListeEmetteurComponent extends Menu {

  idRepresentantLegal: number;
  titre : string = 'Emetteurs';
  columns = [
     {
       columnDef: 'role', 
       header: 'Rôle',
       cell: (element: any) => `${element.role != null ? element.role : ''}`},
     {
       columnDef: 'raisonSociale',
       header: 'Raison sociale',
       cell: (element: any) => `${element.raisonSociale ? element.raisonSociale + ' (' + element.ville + ')' : ''}`
     },
     {
      columnDef: 'typeDosimetrie',
      header: 'Type de dosimétrie',
      cell: (element: any) => `${element.typeDosimetrie != null ? element.typeDosimetrie :''}`
     },
     {
      columnDef: 'id_statut',
      header: 'Statut',
      cell: (element: any) => `${element.id_statut != null ? element.id_statut : ''}`
     }
   ];

   dataSource : PaginationDataSource<any>;
   filtre : ListeEmetteursFiltre;
   reinitialiserTableauSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   constructor(private emetteurService: EmetteurService,
             ....
             ...) {
    super(menuService);
    this.loginService.accedant.subscribe(accedant => {
    this.idRepresentantLegal = accedant.id;
    this.dataSource = new PaginationDataSource(this.emetteurService);
    this.filtre = new ListeAccedantsFiltre();
    this.filtre.idRepresentantLegal = this.idRepresentantLegal;
    this.filtre.sortByParDefaut = 'raisonSociale';
    })
  }
```

In my application there are several roles and in function of the role of the user logged in, the columns must differ : some columns are common to the two roles, and some are specific to a role

How can I code that ?
Declare and use a second array named "columns2"? But how to use it then?